# Playing youtube video in webview in Kitkat

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-4.4-kitkat

I had the following simple piece of code which was playing youtube videos peacefully:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

    });
    mWebView.loadUrl(finalUrl);
```

However, after upgrading my phone to Android 4.4.2, on loading youtube link, the videos dont play.

After some googling, I added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in manifest, but still the problem persists.

Here, my need is to load any url, and IF that happens to be a youtube url, then the whole url should load, with the video in its actual position, and the user should be able to play that

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
    String html = getHTML();
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
}

public String getHTML() {
    String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            + "J2fB5XWj6IE"
            + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
            + "</iframe>\n";
    return html;
}
```

Use this to play the youtube video in an webview.

Comment: Hi Renjith, I'm sorry if I was not very clear in my question. Actually my need is to load any url, and IF that happens to be a youtube url, then the whole url should load, with the video in its actual position, and the user should be able to play that.